# Converting 6 digit number to date

Tags: c#

I would like to convert the string `940226` to the date `26/02/1994`. The code below gives an error saying

> the string is in an incorrect format

```
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
String date = "940226";
Stringdate = DateTime.ParseExact(date, "ddmmyyyy", provider).ToString();
```

Comment: How does it go from 940226 to that date?

Comment: Well your date format seems to be YYMMDD im not surprised it failed.

Comment: Do you know what `ddmmyyyy` means? This is the reason

Comment: If it would try to parse it, you would get the `94th 00:02 26` and also two digits for the year are missing.

Comment: So how can the 94th of January be represented in C#? Or is this a limitation of the .Net Framework?

Comment: If there is a "limitation" it is in the calendar system or Earths lunar cycle. There is no such date as the 94th of January... January has 31 days in it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a format that you are converting **from**, try the following:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(dt, "yyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Note: You also need to use the upper case `MM`, not lower `mm`. Lower is for minutes, upper is for month.

Comment: Additional Info: If anytime you need a two digit number to be interpreted as `20xx` instead of `19xx`, this setting is available in `CultureInfo.Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` (instance, non-static) and as a method overload.